# Fluctuate vs. oscillate

Tags: differences

I understand that you say `hesitate` in the moral context. But what is the difference between oscillation and fluctuation?  Might be you could contrast these with swinging. Is there any difference when to use which?

Comment: As you could see by consulting a dictionary, *oscillate* differs from *fluctuate* usually in the sense that *oscillate* implies a regular, measured, reciprocal change (though some people use it less strictly than that); *fluctuate* just implies a more random kind of change. See also *vacillate*.

Comment: @Robusto The key difference lies in 'reciprocal.'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something that [oscillates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oscillate) repeats a pattern of motion in a regular rhythm, e.g. a pendulum swinging, a spring after it has been compressed or released.

Something that [fluctuates](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluctuate) is observed to change, but irregularly in magnitude or direction (and does not necessarily have both an observable magnitude and direction) e.g. demand, trade, mood

Comment: That much homework should have been done by the asker. Every question is expected to have supporting background effort. This question is thus GR.